# Google Sheets - How to Extract dates list in new column from start date and end date

Tags: google-sheets

i need to extract dates (for each day) between 2 dates (start & end) in new column in google sheet.

The data is:

[image: the data]

The result should be like this:

[image: the result]

i now that it can be done with EXCEL + POWER QUERY

with google sheets i did not find anything
i will be glad if someone will help with that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your locale settings, try:

```
=arrayformula({A1:C1,"DAY";split(query(flatten(array_constrain(if(split(rept(10,C2:C-B2:B+1),0)=1,A2:A&char(9999)&B2:B&char(9999)&C2:C&char(9999)&B2:B+transpose(row(A:A))-1&char(9999),),counta(B2:B),max(C2:C-B2:B)+1)),"where Col1 is not null",0),char(9999))})
```

[image]

Comment: WOW!!! 
Amazing, truly genius.
Very complex formula, works great !!!
Thank you